# What does me'me here stand for?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, abbreviations

The following is a verse from the song Gates of Dawn by the band *Secret Garden*:

> And whose is the hand who raises the sun from the heaving sea?
> The power that ever amazes -
> We look, but never will see.
> Who scattered the seeds so life could be?
> Who coloured the fields of corn?
> Who formed the mould that made me'me before the world was born?

What does the me'me in the lyrics stand for? It looks like some sort of abbreviation. The closest I can think of is "me and me", but it is making no sense for me...

Comment: From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gates+of+Dawn+lyrics&oq=Gates+of+Dawn+lyrics): "Who formed the mould that made me – me," Also checking some music videos on YouTube, I hear "Who formed the mould that made me"

Comment: @EddieKal I hear two `me`'s but I guess I understand how it could be heard as one - the pitch change of the word `made` makes it sound like /meɪeɪd/, where the latter half /eɪd/ somehow sounds ambiguous and can be interpreted as part of `made` but also an extra `me`. If only I can find an official CD insert with lyrics...

Comment: It might be interpreted as "made me [become] me" or "made me [into] me".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Any reference for these?

Comment: @MatthewHui I don't have a reference, it just works for me as I read it. It could be equivalent to "made me what I am" = "made me me"

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty wow that makes a lot of sense!